# Process node growing until eating all memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi, raspbian

This question is the same as my previous one, but since it became too huge by the repeated edit, I prefer to ask it again properly.

I m working on a raspberry pi (raspbian, 512M RAM), and am doing a javascript app in node.js (v0.10.2).

In it, I need to download some video, wich I do by chunk like this:

```
function download (file_url, callback){
    var option={host:url.parse(file_url).host, port:80,path:url.parse(file_url).pathname};
    var file_name=url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();
    var file=fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR+file_name);
    http.get(options, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(data){
            file.write(data);
        }).on('end'), function(){
            file.end();
            callback(DOWNLOAD_DIR+file_name);
        });
    });
};
```

Wich I believe to be similar to [Download large file with node.js avoiding high memory consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771614/download-large-file-with-node-js-avoiding-high-memory-consumption)

The problem is, the rss of the node process don t stop increasing, it s start around 100M, and get killed by the os when around 400M (wich does is the maximal ram).

Since I m new to memory leak tracing and running the app outside of any browser, I either can t use or can t understand how to use memory tool, I ve get the rss from util library.

My question is: why does the rss keep increasing even when I m writing the chunk of data on the fly, and/or where to search for a solution?

EDIT: On second look at the link above, I noticed the use of flags on createWriteStream, but can t find the list nor effect of them, is there anyone here who know any way to access such documentation, it may be related

EDIT2: I m now blindly following the code of Corlosdp, adding the flag a (appends?) make the rss to drop of 2M at random intervals, and make my app last longer, but it still end up killed

EDIT3:I have discovered something interesting

I edited the download function to see where I was in the file:

```
function download (file_url, callback){

    var i=0;

    var option={host:url.parse(file_url).host, port:80,path:url.parse(file_url).pathname};
    var file_name=url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();

    var file=fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR+file_name, {flags:'a', encoding:'binary');

    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(i+"o downloaded");
        console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
    },1000);

    http.get(options, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(data){

            i=i+data.length;

            file.write(data);
        }).on('end'), function(){
            file.end();
            callback(DOWNLOAD_DIR+file_name);
        });
    });
};
```

And the log looked like this:

```
[Downloading the config file]
0o downloaded
0o downloaded
0o downloaded

[logs of the config file getting read, and that the first file start to get downloaded]

986o downloaded
{rss: ...}
6713830o downloaded
{rss:...}
986o downloaded
{rss:...}
14421142o downloaded
{rss: ...}
986o downloaded
{rss:...}
29530702o downloaded
{rss:...}
...
```

It seems there two download in parrallel, but it keep getting stranger when the second file start (in a callback of the first file download), since there s now three different download: the 986 constant, the first file that keep appearing, and the second file!

Doesn t the function supposed to end when the callback is reached?

EDIT5: Silly me, I forgot to clear the interval, wich was why I got this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don t know why my code didn t worked, but thanks to a IRC user, I tried to replace

```
res.on('data', function(data){
    ...
});
```

by

```
res.pipe(file);
```

It work, and don t go over 60M of ram, while I was struggling to don t go over 400M, I don t know why neither do he, but the problem is solved.